# why there is an error in my removestring function

Tags: c++, c

I am making a function called `removeString()`. It's purpose is to remove a string from a text

example: if the text is "the wrong son" and I want to remove "wrong" to be "the son", I use this function.

The prototype is:

```
void removeString(char source[], int start, int numofchrem);
```

and the program is like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void removeString(char source[], int start, int numofchrem)
{
    int i, j, k;
    char n[20];
    j = start + numofchrem - 1;
    for (i = 0; i < numofchrem; i++)
    {
        if (source[start] == '\0')
            break;
        source[j] = '\b';
        j--;
    }
    printf("%s", source);
}

int main()
{
    char text[] = "the wrong son";
    void removeString(char source[], int start, int numofchrem);
    removeString(text, 4, 6);
}
```

when I made the program I debugged first the characters inside the source it was like this

```
"the \b\b\b\b\b\bson"
```

When I print the text inside source using:

```
printf("%s",source);
```

The program showed only "son" not "the son". So if anyone could help me I would be so grateful.

Comment: Well, it prints `the `, then 6 backspaces (thus erasing the previously printed `the `), and finally `son`. Working as expected, I'd say. Perhaps replacing with backspace character `\b` wasn't the wisest approach for implementing `removeString`.

Comment: Please, next time, to a proper question !

Comment: When you print '\b' to the screen followed by something, that something overwrites what was on screen previously. When you print '\b' to the screen with the cursor at the left, nothing happens. In your case you first write "The ", then 6 '\b' (first 4 "go backwards", last 2 do nothing), and then "son" over the 3 first characters of "The ". If you were printing to real paper on an old-style printer, you might see "The" and "son" printed one over the other.

Comment: Why do you use the C++ tag? This is plain C. In C++ you would be supposed to use std::string.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move `"son"` (and the `'\0'`) back, over what you want to replace

```
void removeString(char source[], int start, int numofchrem)
{
    char *d = source + start; // d points to "wrong..."
    char *s = source + start + numofchrem; // s points to "son"
    while (*s != '\0') {
        *d = *s; // replace 'w' with 's', 'r' with 'o', ...
        d++; // point to next: "rong...", "ong...", "ng..."
        s++; // point to next: "on", "n"
    }
    *d = '\0'; // terminate string
}
```